# Use new values from bokeh widgets for interactive python plotting

Tags: python, bokeh, databricks

I need to use the values we receive from Bokeh widgets to run some code and plot newly generated data. I cannot modify the data inside javascript that goes into CustomJS as there not available the libraries that are available in python. I understand that I can use bokeh server and run python callbacks, but this has to happen in a Databricks notebook. Is this possible?

As I cannot expose the code that I am working on, I prepared a sample code that hopefully conveys what I am trying to do.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Grid, LinearAxis, Patches, Plot, Rect
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.resources import CDN


x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
button_cds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(button_val=[1]))
plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(button_cds = button_cds), code="""
        var data = button_cds.data;
        var f = cb_obj.value;
        data['button_val'] = f;
        button_cds.change.emit();
    """)

slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power")
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
for i in range(len(source.data['x'])):
  source.data['y'][i] = x[i]**button_cds.data['button_val'][0]

layout = column(slider, plot)

displayHTML(file_html(layout, CDN))
```

Please note that I can do modifying the `source.data` in CustomJS, but I have to use python code.